# Npgsql freezes while executing query

Tags: c#, npgsql

```
var qrStr = "delete from products where product_ID = 3;";

var qr = new NpgsqlCommand(qrStr, connection);

qr.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

The problem is that when qr is being executed, my program completely freezes. product_ID is foreign key for some table.

I think I would get an Npgsql exception, but this happened.

I use Npgsql of some outdated version still.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a bug. Got Npgsql of last version and now it's working fine.